# How to use phantomjs to click "Load More" button continually until page is fully populated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm very new at learning phantomjs and casperjs and looking for some pointers in how to click a "Load More" button to fully populate a page.  I've looked through similar questions but don't see anything that matches (at least not that I understand).  The idea is to scrape viewer counts off a livestream.com event page.

To start, I can grab the first page in plain text with phantomjs (using cnet as an example) as follows:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://livestream.com/cnet', function() {
    console.log(page.plainText);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

There are quite a number of additional event listings though which require clicking on "Load More".  I would like to extend the above code to do this using the following pseudo code:

```
while ("Load More" exists) {
    click button
    delay to allow page to load
}
```

Inspecting the button element on the above url I found the following:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button thin_border_button black_border small_button ng-binding" ng-click="loadMoreEventsPublic('Archived')" ng-bind="loadMoreText">Load More</a>
```

How can I click (i.e. ng-click="loadMoreEventsPublic('Archived')") repeatedly until the page is fully loaded and then exit phantomjs?

Would it make more sense to do this in casperjs?

Please excuse my extreme noob level, I'm trying to figure this out as much as I can but I need some direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own implementation like the below skeleton

```
function onLoadMoreLinkExists(){
        casper.click("load more link selector");
        casper.then(function(){
            casper.waitFor("load more link selector", onLoadMoreLinkExists, afterAllLoad);
        });
}

function afterAllLoad(){
    // what to do once after all lazy load content loaded
}

casper.waitFor("load more link selector", onLoadMoreLinkExists
}, afterAllLoad);
```

I 've done such kind of implementation while ago & it worked nicely.